# PHP PDO Multiple image INSERT

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert

I'm pretty new at this and getting a hard time building a very simple script for image upload.
I have a input file called `txtfoto` if I insert a single record this works great, but what I trying to do is insert the values of 4 input files called `txtfoto[]` at once. I'm sure that something is wrong or missing in my `PHP` code so any help i'll great.

**HTML:**

```
<label>Imagen: <input name="txtfoto[]"  type="file">
<input name="txtfoto[]"  type="file">
<input name="txtfoto[]"  type="file">
<input name="txtfoto[]"  type="file"></label>
```

**PHP:**

```
    $file = $_FILES["txtfoto"]["name"][$key]
```

mysql sentence:

```
for ($key=0; $key<count($_FILES["txtfoto"]["name"][$key]); $key++){
$sql = "INSERT INTO imagenes (nombre,foto) VALUES (:nombre,:foto)";
$result = $db->prepare($sql);
$result->execute(array(':nombre' => $txtnombre, ':foto' => $file));}
}
```

Comment: you can use the the for loop for the that `for($key=0; $key<count($_FILES["txtfoto"]["name"][$key]); $key++)`

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 Thanks! But still is inserting just one record at time. I need to insert the 4 txtfoto[] input at once.

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 Yes. Please check my code again. I added your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for ($key=0; $key<count($_FILES["txtfoto"]["name"]); $key++){
$file = $_FILES["txtfoto"]["name"][$key];
$sql = "INSERT INTO imagenes (nombre,foto) VALUES (:nombre,:foto)";
$result = $db->prepare($sql);
$result->execute(array(':nombre' => $txtnombre, ':foto' => $file));}
```